# Running python with Flask lib but return "Not Found" page

Tags: python, flask

I am completely new to learning webdev stuffs.

I follow a tutorial on how to upload an image with Flask, and here's the program in Python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify, make_response, url_for
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/upload-image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            image = request.files["image"]

            print(image)

            return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template("upload_image.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But when I try to run the Python on the terminal, it returns local http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but when I opened it, it returns

`Not Found`

`The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Where is the mistake, then?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload-image

Comment: I have tried it but returns `Internal Server Error`

`The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application`

Comment: Without a function decorated with `@app.route('/')`, Flask has nowhere to go when it gets a request for '/'.

Comment: If you are now hitting the `127.0.0.1:5000/upload-image` url then what does your `upload_image.html` file look like?  Also you can run `app.run(debug=True)` for more tips on what went wrong

Comment: You should have logs when you get the 500 error.